# Оптимизация выборки из бд PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть примерно 80 таблиц с данными по которым идёт поиск значений через foreach, и пока он идёт успевает пройти секунд 10-15 так как много таблиц, как сделать так, чтобы вывод данных был моментальный или хотя бы секунды 2 максимум?

Comment: Вынести поиск на сервер БД. Либо статический UNION-запрос, либо, если набор используемых таблиц непостоянен, хранимая процедура.

Comment: опишите проблему более детально, иначе ответа здесь не получите

Answer (score 0):

Вы сразу не можете искать в 80 таблиц одновременно. Должна быть хоть реляционная модель БД. Так, как вы не описали подробно, трудно сказать. Запросы используйте, подзапросы. На Php рекомендую использовать PDO, и сделать правильное подключение к бд. Чтобы при каждом запросе, он не нагружало БД.